# MessagePack and message framing

Tags: python, tcp, buffer, twisted, msgpack

I'm using `MessagePack` to encode/decode my models and send it through a TCP server. At this point, I need to define a delimiter for my messages in order to slice received buffers into correct `MessagePack` objects.

My question is how can I define a delimiter for `MessagePack` and slice messages on the client-side?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You want to use a framing protocol such as [`NetstringReceiver`](https://twistedmatrix.com/documents/15.3.0/api/twisted.protocols.basic.NetstringReceiver.html), and then just unpack your MessagePack messages in `stringReceived`.

Comment: Cool, seems like a good solution but the problem is that, I have clients in other platforms such as C# or C++. Should they implement `Netstring` in their platforms as well?

Comment: Do you control the protocol on the wire, or do you have to deal with existing clients?